# Why does crawling a folder in Linux gets faster with each iteration?

Tags: java, linux, performance, file-io

I have a program in which I need to crawl a specific folder to delete its contents. I am using the Files.walkFileTree method to achieve the same.
On Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit 4GB RAM, although my program runs fine, the first time I start crawling a folder, it takes a very long time. However, on subsequent crawls of the same folder, the time decreases drastically, and settles down.
Here is the output of simple `System.currentTimeInMillis()` calls to check the time spent:

**key**:

- **Deletion** tells the time it took to crawl a folder called 'output' and delete all its contents(Around ~5000 files).
- **Copy** tells the time it took to copy the contents of a small folder over to another place.
- **Crawl** tells the time it took to crawl a directory called 'content', parse its ~5000 files to create corresponding objects + Deletion + Copy [See above].
- **Parse** tells the time it took to actually write the contents of these ~5000 objects into separate files.
  All times are in milliseconds.

**FOLDER A**

On the first time:

```
Deletion: 100100
Copy: 53
Crawl: 143244
Parse: 4307
```

On the second time:

```
Deletion: 486
Copy: 3
Crawl: 1424
Parse: 4581
```

On the third time:

```
Deletion: 567
Copy: 16
Crawl: 1999
Parse: 4027
```

**FOLDER B**
On first time:

```
Deletion: 88971
Copy: 47
Crawl: 137623
Parse: 4125
```

On the second time:

```
Deletion: 443
Copy: 31
Crawl: 1631
Parse: 3986
```

On the third time:

```
Deletion: 434
Copy: 4
Crawl: 1648
Parse: 4048
```

It is to be noted that the **Crawl** time includes time for deletion and copying.
All three operations were performed on the same folder, with the same contents, just minutes apart from each other.
This happens for each new folder that I try this program on. Is this an issue with the file system in place? Or is it something to do with my code?

The code I use to benchmark is here:

```
public void publish(boolean fastParse) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        InfoHandler info = new InfoHandler();
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (fastParse == true) {
            crawler.fastReadIntoQueue(Paths.get(DirectoryCrawler.SOURCE_DIRECTORY).normalize());
        }
        else {
            crawler.readIntoQueue(Paths.get(DirectoryCrawler.SOURCE_DIRECTORY).normalize());
        }
        long read = System.currentTimeMillis();
        info.findLatestPosts(fileQueue);
        //info.findNavigationPages(fileQueue);
        long ps = System.currentTimeMillis();
        parser = new Parser();
        parser.parse(fileQueue);
        info.writeInfoFile();
        long pe = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Crawl: " + (read - start));
        System.out.println("Parse: " + (pe - ps));
    }
```

And the class which defines the readIntoQueue method can be found here:
https://github.com/pawandubey/griffin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pawandubey/griffin/DirectoryCrawler.java

Comment: Did you close your program before the second/third run? Can you try to reboot the system between tests? It could either be your application that caches something, or your system. Depending on the filesystem you use, it could even be some kind of indexing which would improve crawling as well.

Comment: @Peanut the program is run from the command line and basically terminates itself after it's done. And, rebooting the OS basically gives me the first round results again. So I am guessing it is an OS issue.

Comment: Yes. If it is slow after a reboot, it's probably cached in memory, and it stays fast even after a reboot, there's some kind of index mechanism at work. (see answers below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Linux usually pretty aggressively caching everything. It follows a principle — *free RAM is a wasted RAM*. But do not worry, once an app needs more RAM, Linux just drops a cache.

You can run `free` for the system, it would look like:

```
$ free -h
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2,9G       2,7G       113M        55M        92K       1,0G
-/+ buffers/cache:       1,8G       1,1G
Swap:         1,9G       100M       1,8G
```

In the first row, the «used» column *(2,7G)* is amount of memory that is used by the system, including cache. The second row, the same column is amount of a used memory by applications. You can think of the difference between the rows as a free memory, because once an app needed it, the system, as I mentioned, just drops the cache.

You may read more about it [here](http://www.linuxatemyram.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Well, possible answer (from http://www.tldp.org/LDP/tlk/fs/filesystem.html):

> The Linux Virtual File system is implemented so that access to its files is as fast and efficient as possible. It must also make sure that the files and their data are kept correctly. These two requirements can be at odds with each other. The Linux VFS caches information in memory from each file system as it is mounted and used.

So probably your OS just caches files information. In this case program restart won't "help" much (as this is feature of the OS, not your application), and you should reproduce slowness only after OS restart (or maybe there is a way to evict FS data from the caches somehow). You can play with it to prove/disapprove this theory.